# Why I cannot move file under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I followed the tut here http://www.multichain.com/download-install/

When typing

```
mv multichaind multichain-cli multichain-util /usr/local/bin
```

I got permission denied

whereas I am logged with my admin user ubuntu

```
su ubuntu
```

Comment: There is only one admin user named "root" with UID 0. You gain access by using `sudo` in front of a command or `sudo -i` to gain an interactive shell as that user.

Comment: @GiantTree thanks it did work but after that I got another error http://superuser.com/questions/1088424/cannot-execute-on-ubuntu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP indicates in a comment that the question is actually something different, which has already been asked in another question and answered; no answer is required here.