# Cannot execute on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

After installing this http://www.multichain.com/download-install/

I executed this command as explained here http://www.multichain.com/getting-started/

```
multichain-util create chain1
```

I got this error

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 64 bits on VirtualBox

Requirements is

Linux (64-bit), supports Ubuntu 12.04+ according to http://www.multichain.com/download-install/

so why do I get this message ?

[image]

Comment: What does `file multichain-util` gives you (in the correct directory, which can be found with `which multichain-util`)? And `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the website and your question, the program is only for 64bit.
But you have a 32bit system.

You can always check this with `uname -a`: If it printf something with i686 or i386, it's 32 bit. In the other direction, `file programname` (with your program name) will tell you that it is a 64bit executable. They don't match.